# How to access Axios from plain JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Axios in plain JS. I've included it from CDN. In the docs they are creating Axios object like this:
`const axios = require('axios');`

How can I do the same without Node with plain JS?

Comment: Check this might help : https://attacomsian.com/blog/axios-javascript#:~:text=Axios%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,like%20React%2C%20Angular%20and%20Vue.

Comment: Node is still JavaScript.  Do you mean you are trying to access it in a project loaded in a browser?  Are you using any sort of transpilation/build system, or attempting to forgo all of that?

Comment: If u have imported via CDN. No need of node or `require`. `axios` is available to you in the browser. `axios.get(...)` or `axios.post(...)` will do just fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Step 1.** Import Axios CDN using script tag in  tag. For eg.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**Step 2. Use Axios in script tag like this** :-

```
<script>
function handleRequest() {
    axios.post("url", {name: "data"}).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        // do whatever you want if console is [object object] then stringify the response
    })
}
```

You can surely use Axios in html file without nodeJS. Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

In browser environment you don't need to import/require axios, it is available to use globally with `axios` variable.